# how to add some php to this tutorial, mysql query included?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ajax

Tutorial is here: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajaxed-coming-soon-page/

Where it does this:

```
15          $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
16                          SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");
17   
18          if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
19              throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
20          }
```

Once it checks the email is not a duplicate, I would like it to add a unique (no two email records should have the same) Alphanumeric code like this: AQ4ILB9

Then when the user gets the "Thank you!" message in the textbox, I want it to also display the unique code as above.

I have to setup a new column in the DB for the addition of a code, correct? What properties must it have when adding to do the above code insertion? Possibly automatically creating the unique code for each record so the DB does the random code insertion work rather than a loop check in php?

How can I display the code to the user once the "Thank you!" message is displayed.

Any help editing the tutorial would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

**table.sql file**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `coming_soon_emails`
--

CREATE TABLE `coming_soon_emails` (
  `email` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`email`)
) E
```

**ADDITIONAL EDIT**
**hidden div on coming-soon.php**

```
<div id="code">
Thank you! Your code is: <p style="margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $ref_code;?></p>
</div>
```

with that I also had to replace

```
$msg = "Thank you! Subscription Code: " . $email_code;
```

with

```
$ref_code = "example.com/" . $email_code;
```

Now if you check out the script.js file, mine has been modified to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Binding event listeners for the form on document ready

    $('#email').defaultText('Your Email Address');

    // 'working' prevents multiple submissions
    var working = false;

    $('#form').submit(function(){

        if(working){
            return false;
        }
        working = true;

        $.post("./index.php",{email:$('#email').val()},function(r){
            if(r.error){
                $('#email').val(r.error);
            }
            else { $("#form").hide(); $("#code").fadeIn('slow');}

            working = false;
        },'json');

        return false;
    });
});

// A custom jQuery method for placeholder text:

$.fn.defaultText = function(value){

    var element = this.eq(0);
    element.data('defaultText',value);

    element.focus(function(){
        if(element.val() == value){
            element.val('').removeClass('defaultText');
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if(element.val() == '' || element.val() == value){
            element.addClass('defaultText').val(value);
        }
    });

    return element.blur();
}
```

However, the else `{ $("#form").hide(); $("#invite").fadeIn('slow');}` is no longer working! Thoughts?

Comment: How are you generating the alphanumeric code? Why not just use an auto inrement index?   - IF you really wanted a 'code' you could convert the index to hex...    Let me know which way you are going with the code and i can bounce you an example...

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: At the moment it's not being generated. I'm trying to work out the best way for it to be auto-generated, whether through an addition in the script example or in the DB. I'd prefer if the DB created the code and inserted automatically. If that makes sense. Example would be great, thank you! Just need to know what I have to modify in the tutorial php/mysql and the table.sql file which I have now included in the question.

Comment: Are you wanting a 'secure' code or just a short code?

Comment: A random 7 or so digit alphanumeric code :)

Comment: Updated PHP and JS code to fix the 'else' portion of the AJAX if/else clause...

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Added/replaced as you instructed and the form just isn't submitting. Do you have a working txt file url with your working examples? I think your server is down.. Thanks!

Comment: Okay.. well this question is dead (system will allow no more edits on my answer)... Updated and working code avalible at http://colorchallenge.com/comingsoon/comingsoon.txt http://colorchallenge.com/comingsoon/script2.txt demo at http://colorchallenge.com/comingsoon/comingsoon.php That should fix the one issue.. If you need any more help you will have to post a new StackOverflow question

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: PERFECT! I can't thank you enough! I'm sure I'll have a question or two more tomorrow, so stay tuned.. I'll ping ;). Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, to fix the ajax:

```
        if(r.error){
            $('#email').val(r.error);
        } else {
           $('#email').val(r.msg); 
               $("#form").hide(); $("#code").fadeIn('slow');
        }
```

and in the php script fix:

```
    $msg = "Thank you! Subscription Code: " . $email_code;

    if($ajax){
        echo json_encode(array('msg' => $msg)); // add this
        //throw new Exception($msg);  // delete this
    }
```

You will need to modify to suit your variations...

New files:

https://colorchallenge.com/comingsoon/cs.txt (php)

https://colorchallenge.com/comingsoon/script.txt (javascript)

---

http://www.colorchallenge.com/comingsoon/coming-soon.php

http://www.colorchallenge.com/comingsoon/coming-soon.txt

and the SQL:
http://www.colorchallenge.com/comingsoon/table.sql

**New alternate answer with truly random code:**

**Updated SQL Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coming_soon_emails` (   
  `email_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,   
  `email` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,   
  `code` char(7) collate utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   
  PRIMARY KEY  (`email_id`),   
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**in comming-soon.php:**

Add after: "includes/connect.php";

```
function gen_code($codeLen = 7) {
    $code = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$codeLen; $i++) { 
        $d=rand(1,30)%2; 
        $code .= $d ? chr(rand(65,90)) : chr(rand(48,57)); 
    } 
    return $code;
}

function add_code($email_id) {
    $code = gen_code(7);
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE coming_soon_emails SET code='" . $code ."' WHERE email_id='" . $email_id . "'");
    if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1) {
      add_code($email_id);
    } else return $code;
}
```

Then modify:

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){     
    throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.'); 
}
```

To be:

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){     
    throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.'); 
} else {
  $email_code = add_code($mysqli->insert_id);
}
```

Finally, update the message again to include the code...
Change:

```
$msg = "Thank you!";
```

To be:

```
$msg = "Thank you! Subscription Code: " . $email_code;
```

Also (without editing the javascript) to make sure it provides the response you may want to change:

```
    if($ajax){
        die('{"status":1}');
    }

    $msg = "Thank you! Subscription Code: " . $email_code;
```

to:

```
    $msg = "Thank you! Subscription Code: " . $email_code;
    if($ajax){
      throw new Exception($msg);
    }
```

Essentially the last change just makes it always throw an exception..  which then makes sure the message is displayed if its an ajax request

### ---

---

**Full Final Copy of coming-soon.php**

```
<?php

require "includes/connect.php";

function gen_code($codeLen = 7) {     
$code = '';     
for ($i=0; $i<$codeLen; $i++) {         
 $d=rand(1,30)%2;       
 $code .= $d ? chr(rand(65,90)) : chr(rand(48,57));      }  
 return $code; 
 }  


 function add_code($email_id) {
 global $mysqli;
 $code = gen_code(7); 
 $mysqli->query("UPDATE coming_soon_emails SET code='" . $code ."' WHERE email_id='" . $email_id . "'");  
 if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1) {   
 add_code($email_id);  
 } else return $code; } 

$msg = '';

if($_POST['email']){

    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
                        SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

        if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
            throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
        } else {   
          $email_code = add_code($mysqli->insert_id); 
        } 


    $msg = "Thank you! Subscription Code: " . $email_code;

    if($ajax){
        throw new Exception($msg);
    }



    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();        
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>AJAX-ed Coming Soon Page with jQuery and PHP | Tutorialzine Demo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nivo-slider.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="page">

    <h1>Coming Soon</h1>

    <div id="slideshowContainer">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <img src="img/slides/slide1.jpg" width="454" height="169" alt="Coming Soon: Our Awesome Web App">
            <img src="img/slides/slide2.jpg" width="454" height="169" alt="Extensive Functionality">
            <img src="img/slides/slide3.jpg" width="454" height="169" alt="Complete with an iPhone App">
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Subscribe</h2>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $msg?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
    </form>

</div>

<!-- Feel free to remove this footer -->

<div id="footer">
    <div class="tri"></div>
    <h1>AJAX-ed Coming Soon Page</h1>
    <a class="tzine" href="http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajaxed-coming-soon-page/">Read &amp; Download on</a>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you get the edited/updated one (forgot to have add_code return the code on success... just make sure the version you use has a 'return' in add_code and that it has the unique index for the table)

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Using the updated one, the textbox reads: This email already exists in the database.

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Also checked DB - it has inserted the id, email, timestamp, but code is NULL

Comment: @J_C if it is telling you that, then it is not inserting a new row... (my code should not impact insertion of new records) Have you deleted the database table and started over? If not then the email may actually exist in the table... It should only throw that catch/error if it cannot insert a record...

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: I removed the table and imported a saved copy of yours. Then updated the code accordinly. Let me try once again :)

Comment: So it is inserting the record, but not updating the code?  Hmm..  Alright.. done with developing on the fly.. lemme upload some of this code to one of my servers and give it a whirl to see whats up

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Thank you SO MUCH. Seriously cannot thank you enough for your help. It's inserting the record, not adding the code, then doing the check if it's a duplicate and throwing the exception. As far as I can tell that is..

Comment: I spelled 'coming' as 'comming' so it wasnt updating the table...   Update the code update statment and corret the spelling (remove the second 'm' from 'coming' in add_code...

Comment: Okay so after you correct the mispelling above, you need to modify the php so that the ajax outputs the response message...  Just follow the last mod... I tested and it all works now...

Comment: @J_C:  The final copy as of this post should be golden...    Any other problems let me know.. (i think this is my most-edited response yet :)

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: back on - will give this a spin in a sec. Thank you again!!

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Stupid error (500 internal server misconfiguration), error log: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in ...index.php on line 15 which is "global $mysqli;"

Comment: The posted script works for me...  Perhaps a collision with the mysqli... ? Switch all occurences of 'mysqli' in coming-soon.php to 'db'... Then in your 'connect.php'  change @$mysqli and $mysqli-> to be 'db' as well...

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: hmm now blank page. All occurences of $mysqli in coming-soon.php and connect.php are now $db.

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: IT WORKED!! Thank you!!! Are you up for another problem-solver? Should be much easier ;)

Comment: @J_C:   Checkout the links at the top of the answer - demo and code are avalible..    Not sure if i fixed something somewhere - when i first uploaded it i got a 500 error... then fixed one or two minor things and it works.. (also fixed code on StackOverflow - but easier to reference live example..)

Comment: @J_C Depending on the problem - sure... Just post the questoin on S.O. and i will watch your ID for it...  (supposed to be getting work done.. but nice thing about working for myself..)

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Awesome! Thank you so much!! Really appreciate it. Actually the first thing doesn't require a brand new question as it's an addition to before. I set a hidden div on the coming-soon.php / index.php page. Then in the scripts.js I've added jquery to hide the form on a valid submit and display the hidden div with the code.
It used to work, but no longer does. I have updated my original question with the code..

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Just saw your update. So is there any way to have the form hidden and #code div shown, again?

Comment: If you had it working pre-code update, you should be able to modify the new version to get it working again...  Essentially to pass the code back i had the virst version raise an error.. The second version updated the javascript ahd php to pass back the AJAX json variable as msg...

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Added and back to the whole 'not submitting' issue :(. Also the txt files on the server you loaded them up onto aren't loading up on my end..

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to create a new column and set it to be a Unique key. This means that no two rows can have the same value for that column. If you try inserting a value into an Unique row that another row already has, mysql will not. With this being said, you have two options:

Set that row to unique, make it an index, and set it to auto increment. This will make it so that for every row created, a number will be inserted that is 1 more than the previous one (such as 1,2,3,4.. each row basically gets a unique number).

If you want something more than just a unique number, you can use the following code. Just make sure to create a row in the database table called "code" and set it to be a unique key.

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); // Secure input to prevent database injection attacks

// Insert a row into mysql with the e-mail
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
              SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($email)."'");

// Check if row was created successfully (only successful if e-mail is unique)
if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){ // If no row was created, try again.
    throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
}

function genkey($length = 7) // Function to generate a random string
{

    // Set possible characters (characters that can be in the generated string)
    $possible = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 

    // start with a blank string
    $string = "";

    // set up a counter
    $i = 0; 

    // add random characters to $string until $length is reached
    while ($i < $length) 
    { 

        // pick a random character from the possible ones
        $string .= substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
        $i++;

    }

    // done!
    return $string;

}

function make_code($email) // Function to add unique key to database
{

    // Generate a random 7 character string for the unique key. Change the 7 to however long you want the unique code to be.
    $randString = genkey(7);

    // Try insterting a unique key
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE coming_soon_emails
              SET code='" . $string . "' WHERE email='".$email."'");

    // Ensure that row was updated with a unique code. If not, try again with a different code.
    if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){ 
        make_code($email); // Row was not updated since code is not unique. Try again.
    }

}
```

The code is explained in the comments. It basically creates the database row like you were doing before, then tries setting a unique code value for that row. If mysql returns that no rows were updated by the query trying to set a unique code, that means that code was not unique. It will keep trying until a unique code is made.

If you are having trouble setting a column to be unique, auto-increment, and so forth.. take a look into phpMyAdmin. It is excellent for people starting out with this stuff.

Comment: If you want mysql to do it automatically, you will have to make a User Defined Function (UDF). However, that UDF will ultimately be very similar to the code I just gave you above. The only added benefit will be that a mysql UDF will be more efficient CPU wise. However, that performance increase is negligible for something this small unless you are building something on an extremely large scale (many millions of users). As far as I know, mysql as is can only auto-generate unique values that are integers, not strings.

Comment: @user396404: I've edited and placed my code in another answer. Kindly adjust accordingly as it currently does not even submit :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require "includes/connect.php";

function genkey($codeLen = 7) {
    $code = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$codeLen; $i++) { 
        $d=rand(1,30)%2; 
        $code .= $d ? chr(rand(65,90)) : chr(rand(48,57)); 
    } 
    return $code;
}


function make_code($email) // Function to add unique key to database
{

    // Generate a random 7 character string for the unique key. Change the 7 to however long you want the unique code to be.
    $randString = genkey(7);

    // Try insterting a unique key
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE coming_soon_emails
              SET code='" . $string . "' WHERE email='".$email."'");

    // Ensure that the row was updated with a unique code. If not, try again.
$c = $mysqli->fetch_array(query("SELECT count(*) FROM coming_soon_email WHERE code = '$randString'"));

if($c['count(*)'] > 1) // More than one row already has this code. Try again.
{

    make_code($email);  

}


}

$msg = '';

if($_POST['email']){

    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); // Secure input to prevent database injection attacks

// Insert a row into mysql with the e-mail
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO coming_soon_emails
              SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($email)."'");

// Check if row was created successfully (only successful if e-mail is unique)
if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){ // If no row was created, try again.
    throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
}


        if($ajax){
            die('{"status":1}');
        }

        $msg = "Thank you!";
    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();        
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @user396404 @CarpeNoctumDC: That's what I now have and it's not submitting the form. I have also made the 'code' column a UNIQUE key in PhpMyAdmin. Otherwise is there something more efficient?

Comment: It looks like when you were inserting the e-mail row, the value of "code" was blank, which would result in a repeat value for that column. Remove the Unique key label from the "code" column so it is just a regular column. Then, try the updated code above. I made it so that php checks if the "code" value is unique instead of mysql.

Comment: @user396404: Thanks. Still not submitting the form :( it just doesn't want to submit. The 'code' column is just a regular column now.

Comment: The random string is stalling out for some reason

Comment: Any idea why? It's so close!! :)

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Seriously?! Thank you!! I'm hanging tight :)

Comment: Updated a new random numer generator (wont stall out)  ... Havent lookd over all the code...   Try the new generator with his code.. I am going to compile / combine the new generator in with some of my work into a new response...

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Hmm still doesn't seem to submit.. will update code above in 1 sec..

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Just replied to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Better coderandomization:   Plug this into users* code and give it a whirl

```
function genkey($codeLen = 7) {
    $code = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$codeLen; $i++) { 
        $d=rand(1,30)%2; 
        $code .= $d ? chr(rand(65,90)) : chr(rand(48,57)); 
    } 
    return $code;
}
```

---

Origional response:

If you simply want to work with a simple unsecure code instead of an email address, you could use hex plus a base for a 'code' value...

First, update your table so it has an auto increment primary key, and email as a secondary unique key..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coming_soon_emails` (
  `email_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `email` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`email_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then, in the example code (comming-soon.php around line 17) modify:

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
    throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
}
```

to be:

```
if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
   throw new Exception('This email already exists in the database.');
} else {
   $email_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
   $email_code = dechex($email_id + 1000000);  // just makes the code longer
}
```

Finally, change comming-soon.php (around line 28) from:

```
    $msg = "Thank you!";
```

To be:

```
    $msg = "Thank you! Subscription ID: " . $email_code;
```

Then if you want to work with unsubscribe you simply unhex the number and subtract whateverwas added to it (10000000 in my example)...

It just depends on how 'secure' you want the code...  The other examples given are great for security.. But if your simply wanting a code instead of email, the hex route is the simplest...

Comment: Thanks! Your code is generating an ID, such as: first record, $email_code = 1, second record, $email_code = 2, etc. I'd love for this to be randomised and alphanumeric if possible?

Comment: Well the dechex should convert the email id to a hexidecimal code... (so the code returned should be a hex value)... If you want it randomized you need to implement something like user396404 suggested...

Comment: Yup randomised and alphanumeric. sorry